# Proving by Möbius' inversion formula if $\frac n{\phi(n)}=\sum\limits_{d\mid n}f(d)$ then $f(n)=\frac{\mu^2(n)}{\phi(n)}$

Tags: number-theory

> Prove by Möbius' inversion formula if $\dfrac n{\phi(n)}=\sum\limits_{d\mid n}f(d)$ then $f(n)=\dfrac{\mu^2(n)}{\phi(n)}$.
>   Notice $\phi$ is the Euler totient function and $\mu$ is the Mobius function.

Recall that Möbius' inversion formula  states if $g(n)=\sum\limits_{d\mid n}f(d)$, then $f(n)=\sum\limits_{d\mid n}\mu(d)g\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)$. In this question, $g(n)=\dfrac{n}{\phi(n)}$, then $$f(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)g(\frac{n}{d})=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\frac{\frac{n}{d}}{\phi(\frac{n}{d})}.$$

From this I got trouble in simply the last equation.

I have read a similar question about prove $\dfrac{n}{\phi(n)}=\sum\limits_{d\mid n}\dfrac{\mu^2(d)}{\phi(d)}$. But they were using the fact that both sides are multiplicative.

Comment: I also get trouble when prove the last form. I tried using multiplicative function by use f(n)=f(d)*f(n/d), but it can't go the last result!!!